# getting value from checkbox to pass into angular function when checked

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular

I'm making a list of checkboxes that each have a different string value, one of `heading`, `paragraph`, `list`, `table`, `visualtitle`. I feel like the current method of `(change)="onChange('heading', $event.target.checked)` isn't the correct way to code this part, and would like to make use of the `name="annotationtype"` field so I can use the checked values in other locations as well. How do I get this value?

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="widget-container">
      <label class="checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('heading', $event.target.checked)" />Heading</label>
      <label class="checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('paragraph', $event.target.checked)" />Paragraph</label>
      <label class="checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('list', $event.target.checked)" />List</label>
      <label class="checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('table', $event.target.checked)" />Table</label>
      <label class="checkbox-label"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('visualtitle', $event.target.checked)" />Visual Title</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
  onChange(name: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    if (!this.urlhash)
    {
      alert("Query URL cannot be empty!!!");
    }
    else
    {
      if (isChecked) {
        this.checkedAnnotations.push(new FormControl(name));
      } else {
        const index = this.checkedAnnotations.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === name);
        this.checkedAnnotations.removeAt(index);
      }
      var url = `/sd_api/htmlview/${this.urlhash}/highlighted.html?annotypes=${this.checkedAnnotations.value.join()}&datasource=${this.datasource}`;
      console.log(url);
      this.iframe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best idea is to leverage Angular's way of doing things. In this case, the `Forms API` from `@angular/forms`.

You can harness this api to do most of the heavy lifting. Bind `formControlName` to the `FromGroup` object and use the values from the keys that you set up.

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formB: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formB.group({
      checkBox1: [false],
      checkBox2: [false],
    });
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

Template

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="widget-container">
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkBox1" />Heading1
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkBox2" />Heading2
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This way you get used to working with the tools Angular has for these run of the mill situations.